# How do I make a div sit to the right of a flex container that has its direction set to column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flex for the title bar and also for the navigation bar on my page.

The title bar should go along the top of the screen, and the navigation bar should reside on the left.

The content should appear below the title bar, and to the right of the navigation bar.

However, I have not (yet) been able to figure out how to get the content to appear to the right of the navigation bar (it wants to go on the next line below it).

```css
.flex-container-1 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
}

.flex-body-1 {
  padding: 1em;
}

.content-body {
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
}

.flex-body-1:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: skyblue;
}

.flex-container-2 {
  display: flex;
  width: min(90%, 100em);
  /* have a width which is the lesser of these two compared to viewport */
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: max(1em, 2vh);
  /* choose whichever is bigger- 2% of viewport height, or 1em */
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 10em;
}

.nav-items {
  width: 10em;
}

.nav-items:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flex-2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex-container-1">
    <div class="flex-body-1">Home</div>
    <div class="flex-body-1">About</div>
    <div class="flex-body-1">Contact</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-body">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <div class="nav-items">Item 1</div>
      <div class="nav-items">Item 2</div>
      <div class="nav-items">Item 3</div>
      <div class="nav-items">Item 4</div>
      <div class="nav-items">Item 5</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Main content</h1>
      <p>This is the main page of information that I want to display on my page.</p>
      <p>IT should sit to the right of the nav elements which should go along the left side of the page.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: flex only has _one_ main axis. If you want your header to go over the full width, and have two columns next to each other below that - then you could either "fake" this by laying out your flex items as columns, letting them wrap, and making the first "column" take 100% width. But it would be cleaner, IMHO, if side menu and main content would share a flex parent of their own. Or, you go look into `grid`, which does more or less what flex does - but for two axis at the same time.

Comment: thanks heaps @CBroe.  you're right - grid is probably the best option for this particular layout.  I've been teaching myself grid and flexbox - and seeing what I can do with each.  putting the menu and the content into their own flexbox does seem to resolve the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey if I understood your problem correctly, here is the solution.

You just need to make the 'content-body' a flex container and use the property 'justify-content:space-between' (also try 'justify-content:space-around' may suit you better). And I also recommend you to set default margin and padding 0 at the top of your css to make sure that the ugly margin and padding on the heading and 2 paragraphs on doesnt mess up the design.

Here's the modified css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content-body {
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: thanks heaps for that @ayus_98.  I think that resolves it.  (I'll add other margins/padding to various elements directly to adjust the relative layout. Also, I set the justify-content to "left" - which seems to suit better.  but thanks heaps for showing how this layout could be done :)